# What is a conventional material in electromagnetism?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, material-science

We have an assignment question that asks to justify $\alpha > 1$ for a conventional material, where $\alpha^2 = \left(\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon_0} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sigma }{\omega \epsilon_0 } \right)^2 $.
However, when I search up what are conventional materials in electromagnetism, it seems to be assumed knowledge, so I'm just wondering what exactly the definition of a conventional material is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think conventional material just means in contrast to a ["metamaterial"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamaterial) which might have a negative permittivity or relative permittivity $<1$.